# AWS account programatic access via mac cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-authenticator

In my  `~/.aws/credentials` file I have two profiles:  `default` and `user1`.

`user1` keys are tied to a different AWS account.

I can access default account.

I am unable to access the `user1` AWS account:

For example, when I pass this command:

```
aws s3 ls --profile user1
```

This message is displayed:

> An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Another user is able to use these same keys to access this account so the keys are valid.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: may be try upgrading to the latest version if not already running the latest version.

Comment: @Asdfg- yes running the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of the profiles works.

Time on your system might be out of sync.

You can sync time on Mac systems using

`Big Sur`

```sh
sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com
```

On `Mojave`

in case of error

```sh
kod_init_kod_db(): Cannot open KoD db file /var/db/ntp-kod: No such file or directory
```

create the file and change ownership to root. Some people reported this was actually breaking the ntp synchronization

```sh
sudo touch /var/db/ntp-kod
sudo chown root:wheel /var/db/ntp-kod
```

and the run

```sh
sudo sntp -sS pool.ntp.org
```

There are more options in this post[How can I tell if my Mac is keeping the clock updated properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117865/314762) you can try to sync the time.

EDIT:

As the OP got updated, it works for one profile but doesn't for the second one. In that, as @Asdfg suggested,

- Double check the keys you have in your profile if they are correct
- upgrade the AWS CLI and in case the error persists,
- last but not least follow the [Troubleshooting AWS CLI errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-troubleshooting.html)

Comment: `sntp -sS time.apple.com`
Password:
sntp 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Tue Mar 21 14:36:42 UTC 2017 (139~6597)
kod_init_kod_db(): Cannot open KoD db file /var/db/ntp-kod: No such file or directory
2021-01-27 14:05:31.407190 (+0600) -0.001341 +/- 0.001122 time.apple.com 17.253.6.253 s1 no-leap                              - This was the output on the screen- Did not solve the problem- same error message popped up

Comment: @Jay I added more information in the answer, that can help you sync the time on your machine.

Comment: thanks @samtoddler -- so- one account on AWS could be accessed and another not if time is not synced?

Comment: @Jay I am assuming none works because in the OP you didn't mention if the `default` profile works for you.

Comment: oh- sorry! Default works. just user1 doesnt- I have made the change in my question now

Comment: @Jay in that case I suggest upgrading the `AWS CLI` the very first step and  if the error persists follow  [Troubleshooting AWS CLI errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-troubleshooting.html) guide.

Comment: I do have the latest version:    aws-cli/2.1.1 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.6.0 exe/x86_64.  I will do as you suggest and look at the trouble shooting link -  I dont need to put in the AWS account anywhere to use a profile do I?  I am just using the access keys

Comment: @Jay yes you just need `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` and I am assuming here you are not using session-based tokens here. If you are using session-based tokens or let's say assuming an `IAM Role` you need to provide a third var named `aws_session_token`

Comment: Check AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID environment variables to make sure they are not set. Also try opening the file in vi or nano just to be sure there are no extra/weird characters at the end of your keys. Finally, try generating new keys and see what happens.

Comment: samtoddler: correct, not using session-based-tokens.         Asdfg: No environment variables. and no extra/weird characters. there is a plus sign in the middle of the secret access key but these keys are working for another person on their mac but not on mine

Comment: @samtoddler and Asdfg:   Thanks so much for your help! I finally figured out the problem was - there was a number 0 in the real access key and the key I was provided had the letter  O-   I am not quite sure how that happened but now the problem is solved:)

Comment: @John Rotenstein Thank you for editing my question- first time here:) I appreciate all the help